# Vectorize double sum of cross-wise product of matrix elements

Tags: matrices

I would like to find the matrix multiplication (vectorized) equivalent of the following operation.

Given are two matrices $A$ and $B$ of dimension $m$ by $n$, respectively. I seek to vectorize by matrix multiplication double sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}b_{ij}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner sum is the $ii$ component of $A B^T$. The whole sum is $
\mathrm{tr} AB^T$.

Comment: Thanks, using your answer I could prove it for myself.